# Monopoly game problems

Tags: java, collections, frequency

I have a problem in a class, Shipping, in my monopoly game. I want to find out how many shippings a player owns and thereby determine the rent. (It is a danish version of the game, so i think the rules differ from country to country). I use the Collections.frequency but for some reason it always goes to the else statement and gives me 8 times the rent. Here is the code:

```
package fields;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Shipping extends Ownable
{
    public int rent;
    private int occurence;
    private String yesOrNo;
    private Shipping shipping;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

public Shipping(int fieldNumber, String fieldName, int price)
{
    super(fieldNumber, fieldName, price);
    this.rent = 500;
}

public int getRent()
{
    return rent;
}

@Override
public int getPrice()
{
    return price;
}

@Override
public String getName()
{
    return fieldName;
}

@Override
public int getNumber()
{
    return fieldNumber;
}

@Override
public matador.Player getOwner()
{
    return owner;
}

@Override
public void getConsequence()
{
    if(getOwner() == null)
    {
        System.out.println("Do you want to buy it? (Y/N)");
        yesOrNo = scan.next();

        if(yesOrNo.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
        {
            matador.Main.currentPlayer.money -= getPrice();
            owner = matador.Main.currentPlayer;
            matador.Main.currentPlayer.ownedGrounds.add((Shipping) data.board[matador.Main.currentPlayer.getPosition()]);
            System.out.println(matador.Main.currentPlayer.getName()
                    + " bought " + getName());
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(matador.Main.currentPlayer.getName() +
                    " did not buy " + data.board[matador.Main.currentPlayer.getPosition()].getName());
        }
    }
    else if(getOwner() != matador.Main.currentPlayer)
    {
        occurence = Collections.frequency(owner.ownedGrounds, shipping);
        if(occurence == 1)
        {
            System.out.println(matador.Main.currentPlayer.getName() + " needs to pay " +
                    owner.getName() + " " + getRent());
            matador.Main.currentPlayer.money -= getRent();
            owner.money += getRent();
        }
        else if(occurence == 2)
        {
            System.out.println(matador.Main.currentPlayer.getName() + " needs to pay " +
                    owner.getName() + " " + (2 * getRent()));
            matador.Main.currentPlayer.money -= (2 * getRent());
            owner.money += (2 * getRent());
        }
        else if(occurence == 3)
        {
            System.out.println(matador.Main.currentPlayer.getName() + " needs to pay " +
                    owner.getName() + " " + (4 * getRent()));
            matador.Main.currentPlayer.money -= (4 * getRent());
            owner.money += (4 * getRent());
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(matador.Main.currentPlayer.getName() + " needs to pay " +
                    owner.getName() + " " + (8 * getRent()));
            matador.Main.currentPlayer.money -= (8 * getRent());
            owner.money += (8 * getRent());
        }
    }
}
}
```

I think the problem is the object i try to get the frequency of, but i have no idea.

thanks in advance!

Regards!

Comment: Have you tried to debug? Set a breakpoint and have a look inside your collection

Comment: The _frequency_ is most probable 0. So it is neither 1, nor 2, nor 3, and thus the else branch is taken. The reason might be that you didn't provide a proper `equals` method (and thus also a proper `hashCode` method) in your `Shipping` class.

Comment: just a short codereview: the code in the if/elses is identical. extract it into a method, with the number (1,2,4,8 * getRent()) and the Player and Owner as arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
occurence = Collections.frequency(owner.ownedGrounds, shipping);
```

`Collections.frequency` relies on the object's `equals` method to compare the objects in the Collection to the object whose occurrences you wish to find. Since your `Shipping` class doesn't seem to override `equals`, is uses `Object`'s default implementation, which compares the references.

Therefore you will always get a frequency of `0` (unless you pass a `Shipping` reference that is already in the `Collection`, in which case you would get a frequency of `1`, but it would probably still be the wrong result).

Answer (score 0):

[Collections.frequency(c, o)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency(java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.Object)) uses the equals() method for comparison. I can see that you've not overridden it with your own implementation, therefore it will default to Object.equals() which uses references.

Although not strictly needed for this problem you [should also implement .hashCode() when implementing equals()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java).

This is stated sort-of in the javadoc.

> Returns the number of elements in the specified collection equal to
>   the specified object. More formally, returns the number of elements e
>   in the collection such that (o == null ? e == null : o.equals(e)).